# Query with LINQ where Context matches multiple parameters from a List of Objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core

Presumed I have a table "Article" with multiple columns, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Article (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  ProducerId INT NOT NULL,
  Barcode nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  DescriptionText nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  ActiveFlag BIT NOT NULL
)
```

In my ASP.NET Core application I am using LINQ to query that table, e.g.:

```
IQueryable<Article> query = _context.Article
                     .Where( p => p.Active == true );
```

That works of course.
Now I am getting some parameter, which is a very simple Object with a **List < ArticleQuery >** or alternativly a **IEnumerable < ArticleQuery >**.

ArticleQuery.cs:

```
public class ArticleQuery
{
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<ArticleRequest> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleRequest
{
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

Actually I have no clue how to integrate that into LINQ. I tried lots of stuff, but in the end I never figured out to get something like this join:

```
IQueryable<Article> query = _context.Article
    .Join(articleQuery.ArticleRequest,
        x => new { a = x.Barcode, b = x.Barcode},
        y => new { a = y.ProducerId, b = y.ProducerId},
        (x, y) => x);
```

Also this pseudo-code didn't work (but the Join seems to be the better try):

```
IQueryable<Article> query = _context.Article.Where( p => 
   p.Active == true &&
   articleQuery.ArticleRequest.ProducerId.Contains(p.ProducerId) && 
   articleQuery.ArticleRequest.Barcode.Contains(p.Barcode)
);
```

Any ideas how that works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. Not that perfect, but it's working.

I created a new database for my webservice with a table "RequestArticles":

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RequestArticle(
    RequestId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    ProducerId INT NOT NULL,
    Barcode NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

I wrote my requests into that table:

```
Guid requestGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
foreach (var requestArticle in requestedArticles.Articles) requestArticle.RequestId = requestGuid;
_context.RequestArticle.AddRange(requestedArticles.Articles); //IEnumerable list of articles
_context.SaveChanges();
```

After that I just manually joined my new request-table.

```
IQueryable<Articles> query = _context.Articles.FromSql<Articles>(
    @"SELECT      a.*, ra.Barcode AS RequestedBarcode
      FROM        dbo.Articles a
      INNER JOIN  Webservice.dbo.RequestArticle ra
              ON  ra.ProducerId = a.ProducerId AND ra.Barcode = a.Barcode
      WHERE       ra.RequestId = {1}",
    requestGuid);
```

At the moment I am suffering to replace the new static database-name within the SQL-String with a different string from my new context, but the basics work fast like a charm. Even though it's not the solution I was hoping for, as I thought LINQ+EF are smarter than that. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is a situation that normal LINQ to Entities code can't handle very well.

The syntax you'd *want* to use looks like this:

```
IQueryable<Article> query = _context.Article
    .Where( p => 
       p.Active == true &&
       articleQuery.ArticleRequest.Any(
           r => r.ProducerId == p.ProducerId && 
                r.ArticleRequest.Barcode == p.Barcode
       )
    );
```

Unfortunately, LINQ to Entities can't handle mixing in-memory collections into database queries like this.

In theory, you could represent your ArticleRequest as a model in the database and perform a query similar to the one above, but based on an `IQueryable<ArticleRequest>` from your context rather than just a parameter variable. But that would be a terribly hacky workaround.

Some people resort to materializing the entire set of `Article` objects so they can use a LINQ to Objects provider:

```
IQueryable<Article> query = _context.Article
    .AsEnumerable() // DANGER: materializes *all* the articles
    .Where( p => 
       p.Active == true &&
       articleQuery.ArticleRequest.Any(
           r => r.ProducerId == p.ProducerId && 
                r.ArticleRequest.Barcode == p.Barcode
       )
    );
```

But this approach won't scale well as you get more articles.

Another approach is to build expressions trees dynamically, which would result in an Expression that looks like this:

```
    p => 
       p.Active == true &&
       ((p.ProducerId == 12 && p.BarCode == "12345") ||
        (p.ProducerId == 13 && p.BarCode == "54321") ||
        ...
       )
```

But the code required to produce this kind of statement dynamically is pretty ugly and very difficult to understand.

A better solution would probably be to use a bunch of Unions. One concise way to represent that is:

```
IQueryable<Article> query = articleQuery.ArticleRequest.Aggregate(
    _context.Article.Where(p => false),
    (q, r) => q.Union(context.Article.Where(p => 
           r.ProducerId == p.ProducerId && 
           r.ArticleRequest.Barcode == p.Barcode))
)
    .Where(p => p.Active == true);
```

This will produce a SQL query that unions the results of several one-off queries against each other. With a little more C# code, you could remove the superfluous "Where False" part of the query.

There are other libraries like [Dynamic LINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) and [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) which are designed to help with this sort of problem, but it's been a long time since I've played with them and I can't vouch for how well they'll work against modern versions of Entity Framework.

Alternatively, you can avoid using LINQ entirely and just construct some custom SQL for this one query. That's probably what I'd do. Just be careful to guard against SQL injection on that barcode!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer! The query syntax worked after I tried the query with less data as it was running into a timeout before. That kind of querying seems **way too slow**. The "hacky solution" with my Articles in memory wont work, as there are 200 million entries in there. I guess I will insert those article-queries into my database and then just join that stuff within the database. That's not what I was hoping for, but it seems to be straight-forward.

Comment: Yeah, when you're dealing with hundreds of millions of rows, you often have to sacrifice straightforward code to get acceptable performance. Best of luck!

Comment: Now I tried to create the expression-tree dynamically. That worked like a charm, but as soon as I am querying more than a ~100 barcode/producer combinations, my code changes from 300ms response-time to time-out. I guess the expression-tree has a maximum size defined somewhere. The resulting SQL is a little ugly but _should_ work:

Comment: `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[ProducerId], [t].[Barcode], [t].[DescriptionText]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__a_136) [p0].*
    FROM [Article] AS [p0]
    WHERE [p0].[ActiveFlag] IS NULL AND (
 (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
 (((((([p0].[ProducerId] = @__requestedArticle_ProducerId_0) AND ([p0].[Barcode] = @__BarCode_1)) 
  OR (([p0].[ProducerId] = @__requestedArticle_ProducerId_2) AND ([p0].[Barcode] = @__BarCode_3))) 
  OR (([p0].[ProducerId] = @__requestedArticle_ProducerId_10) AND ........)))))........`

Comment: @Stix: If your application expects an unbounded number of query items, then I'd definitely go with the table-join method. If that's not something you expect users to do, then I'd put a guard statement in to block queries with more than a reasonable number.